# Flutter: ListView.builder + MultiImagePicker2

Tags: android, flutter, mobile

Im currently working on an app where it gets the pictures from galleries, then listing them out. But i cant seem to get it right. Currently facing an issue where i get the error

"_TypeError (type 'Future' is not a subtype of type 'Widget')".

any ideas

```
// ignore_for_file: prefer_const_constructors

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:multi_image_picker2/multi_image_picker2.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';

class TestPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const TestPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _TestPageState createState() => _TestPageState();
}

class _TestPageState extends State<TestPage> {
  List<Asset> claims = <Asset>[];

  final ImagePicker imgpicker = ImagePicker();
  List<Asset>? imagefiles;

  loadLimitedImages() async {
    try {
      var pickedfiles = await MultiImagePicker.pickImages(maxImages: 3);
      if (pickedfiles != null) {
        setState(() {
          imagefiles = pickedfiles;
        });
      } else {
        print("No image is selected.");
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print("error while picking file.");
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          'Testing Functions',
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.black),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
          child: Center(
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                imagefiles != null ? loadLimitedImages() : Container(),
                imagefiles?.length == 3
                    ? Container()
                    : IconButton(
                        onPressed: () => loadLimitedImages(),
                        icon: Icon(Icons.camera_enhance),
                        iconSize: 100,
                      ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I can only have 3 max images and it must be stacked in a row, when the images are picked, it goes back to the screen. If 3 images are showing, the camera icon dissapears, if not it will be beside the picked images if less than 3.

Answer (score 0):

You get this error because of the following line in your `build()` method.

```dart
imagefiles != null ? loadLimitedImages() : Container(),
```

Here you call `loadLimitedImages()` which will return a `Future`, which is not a Widget. That method does not return anything, so this won't work in the way you try to use it.

If I understand it correctly, you want to pick 3 images, that operation should be a result of an action, e.g. a user taps a button to pick images. That is where you can call your `loadLimitedImages()` method. You shouldn't call such a method inside the `build()` method, since it could run frequently. The `build()` method's purpose is to build the UI based on the current state.

If you need to pick images without user interaction you can initiate it in the `initState()` of your `State`.